# Need Help! User String Input that Counts Vowels

Tags: python, string, function, count

This a school work assignment that has me stumped. It has to involved a main function.

Write a program that prompts the user to enter a string, then sends the string to a function
called countVowels(stringToCheck) which determines the number of vowels in the string and returns that
value.

```
def main():
    print('This program will calculate the number of vowels in a string of characters.')
    stringInput = input('Enter a string: ')
    countVowels(stringInput)

def countVowels(stringToCheck):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for currentChar in stringToCheck:
        if stringToCheck in vowels:
            count = 0
            count = count + 1
        print('This string contains', count, 'vowels.')
    
main()
```

Comment: please format your code as code (``` instead of **)

Comment: What is your question? `currentChar` is unused. You should probably use it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple edits to your code

1. you were looping through the StringToCheck, so it was looking to see if the entire string was in vowels, not just one character
2. the print statement was within the for loop, so it was printing out the number of vowels for each loop
3. you set count to 0 in each loop, which defeats the point of counting

```
def main():
    print('This program will calculate the number of vowels in a string of characters.')
    stringInput = input('Enter a string: ')
    countVowels(stringInput)


def countVowels(stringToCheck):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    count = 0
    for currentChar in stringToCheck:
        if currentChar in vowels:
            count = count + 1
    print('This string contains', count, 'vowels.')

main()
```

Comment: I changed the location of the count = 0 as you have here. I have never posted on here and accidentally cut off the top say def main():
The issues I'm still having is the teacher is requiring a def main() for it. He also wants the output to display like this
"The string contains 3 vowels."
Instead mine comes out as "This string contains 1 vowels." and "This string contains 2 vowels." When the input is eerr by example

Comment: i added the def main back in after i saw your edit. Printing twice happens becuase you originally had the print statement within the for loop (I just changed the indentation for you)

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code:

```
count = 0
def main():
    print('This program will calculate the number of vowels in a string of characters.')
    stringInput = input('Enter a string: ')
    countVowels(stringInput)

def countVowels(stringToCheck):
        count = 0
        vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
        for currentChar in stringToCheck:
            for CurrentElement in vowels:
                if currentChar == element:
                    count = count + 1
        print('This string contains', count, 'vowels.')
    
main()
```

Let's go through what I did.

I first changed the `vowel` variable into a list, since it is easier and more efficient to hold multiple values that way. In the function `countVowels()`, I added a for loop to check if the `currentChar` is in the `currentElement` of the `vowels` variable. If so, it increases `count` by one.

I tested this, and it works for me.

Good luck!